# How to create a heatmap with continuous scale using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have got a data frame with several 1000 rows in the form of

```
group = c("gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3")
pos = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
color = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2)
df = data.frame(group, pos, color)
```

and would like to make a kind of heatmap in which one axes has a continuous scale (position). The color column is categorical. However due to the large amount of data points I want to use binning, i.e. use it as a continuous variable.

This is more or less how the plot should look like:
[image]

I can't think of a way to create such a plot using ggplot2/R. I have tried several geometries, e.g. geom_point()

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=strain, y=pos, color=color)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors=c("yellow", "black", "orange"))
```

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your picture looks more like a stacked barplot rather than a heatmap. Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: I know, but I was not able to make it with geom_bar().

Comment: Wouldn't something like `ggplot(df)+geom_tile(aes(x=group,y=pos,fill=as.factor(color)))` work?

Comment: You can also try:  `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group, y=pos, fill=factor(color))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
library(ggplot2)
group = c("gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr1","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3","gr3")
pos = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
color = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2)
df = data.frame(group, pos, color)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = group, y = pos)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = color))
```

Looks like this 
[image]

Improved version with 3 color gradient if you like

```
library(scales)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = group, y = pos)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = color))+ scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("orange","black","yellow"),values=rescale(c(1, 2, 3)),guide="colorbar")
```

[image: Version 2 with 3 color gradient of your choice]

Comment: library(scales) instead if library(scale)

Comment: thank you for your quick repsonse. When I use 20000 instead of 10 datapoints per group than very thin lines are plottet. Is there a to make it more smooth? Is it possible to rename the ticks of the color legends (e.g. 3.0 => good, 2.0 => ok, 1.0 => bad) and remove the other ticks?

Comment: can you upload the whole data somewhere so I can play with it and send you a better solution